# Making bedikas chometz early -- ossur in malacha, eating, learning?

Tags: halacha, passover, melacha-creative-work, travel

When someone leaves their home within 30 days of Pesach without someone to be bodek it from chometz, they themselves have to be bodek it early (See Siman 436.) In the normal case of bedikas chometz one may not do malacha, eat or learn before making the bedika once the time as come (and even a half hour before) to make the bedika (See Siman 431.) Do these same dinim apply to someone who will be making a bedika early before leaving their house?

Comment: I found in my notes that the Pri Megadim in Siman 436 Sif-Katan 1 is machmir however I can't seem to find it in the PM"G inside

Comment: The Zman wont come until Erev Pesach, is there a reason to say the Zman is pushed back in this case? This is interesting

Comment: http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Bedikat_Chametz#cite_note-34